# Using sed to extract a substring in curly brackets

Tags: bash, sed

I've currently got a string as below:

```
integration@{Wed Nov 19 14:17:32 2014} branch: thebranch
```

This is contained in a file, and I parse the string. However I want the value between the brackets `{Wed Nov 19 14:17:32 2014}`

I have zero experience with Sed, and to be honest I find it a little cryptic.

So far I've managed to use the following command, however the output is still the entire string.

What am I doing wrong?

```
sed -e 's/[^/{]*"\([^/}]*\).*/\1/'
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To get the values which was between `{`, `}`

```
$ sed 's/^[^{]*{\([^{}]*\)}.*/\1/' file
Wed Nov 19 14:17:32 2014
```

Answer (score 5):

This is very simple to do with `awk`, not complicate regex.

```
awk -F"{|}" '{print $2}' file
Wed Nov 19 14:17:32 2014
```

It sets the field separator to `{` or `}`, then your data will be in the second field.

`FS` could be set like this to:

```
awk -F"[{}]" '{print $2}' file
```

---

To see all field:

```
awk -F"{|}" '{print "field#1="$1"\nfield#2="$2"\nfield#3="$3}' file
field#1=integration@
field#2=Wed Nov 19 14:17:32 2014
field#3= branch: thebranch
```

Answer (score 2):

This might work

```
sed -e 's/[^{]*\({[^}]*}\).*/\1/g'
```

Test

```
$ echo "integration@{Wed Nov 19 14:17:32 2014} branch: thebranch" | sed -e 's/[^{]*{\([^}]*\)}.*/\1/g'
```

Wed Nov 19 14:17:32 2014

**Regex**

- `[^{]*` Matches anything other than the `{`, That is `integration@`
- `([^}]*)` Capture group 1

  - `\{` Matches `{`
  - `[^}]*` matches anything other than `}`, That is `Wed Nov 19 14:17:32 2014`
  - `\}` matches a `}`
- `.*` matches the rest

Answer (score 1):

Simply, below command also get the data...

```
echo "integration@{Wed Nov 19 14:17:32 2014} branch: thebranch" | sed 's/.*{\(.*\)}.*/\1/g'
```